# Im a Nigeria citizen leave in italy and i have permanent stay and im married to an italian citizen can i go to uk without visa

Tags: schengen

Im a  Nigeria leaving in italy and i have permanent permit of stay and im married to italian citizen can i travel to uk with out visa

Comment: If the linked duplicate does not answer your question, please advise by posting a comment here.